# Is there any way to remove navigation animation for bottomNavigation bar in scaffold in jetpack compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I am using scaffold for my screen and there is a `bottomNavigationBar` inserted in `bottomBar` function.

When I click on an item in `bottomNavigationBar`, I navigate to another screen with this bar and Jetpack Compose uses it's default transition animation that looks like fading.

But the bottom `navigationBar` also fades during transition and this looks awful because I want it to have no animations at all.

Is there any way to remove transition animation for `bottomNavigationBar`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In according to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#nav-to-composable), animation for navigation is tracked by [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172112072).

As you can see in the last comment, the animation API for navigation is currently provided by the respective [accompanist library](https://github.com/google/accompanist). But, in the future it will be moved back to the standard navigation library. So, for now, I suggest you to use the Accompanist library instead of the "default" one.

If you're doing that already, you can replace the animation using something like this:

```
AnimatedNavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = ROUTE_MAIN,
    enterTransition = {
        if (initialState.destination.route == ROUTE_MAIN) {
            EnterTransition.None
        } else {
            slideInHorizontally(
                initialOffsetX = { it },
                animationSpec = tween(300)
            )
        }
    },
    exitTransition = {
        if (initialState.destination.route == ROUTE_MAIN) {
            ExitTransition.None
        } else {
            slideOutHorizontally(
                targetOffsetX = { -it },
                animationSpec = tween(300)
            )
        }
    },
    popEnterTransition = {
        if (targetState.destination.route == ROUTE_MAIN) {
            EnterTransition.None
        } else {
            slideInHorizontally(
                initialOffsetX = { -it },
                animationSpec = tween(300)
            )
        }
    },
    popExitTransition = {
        if (targetState.destination.route == ROUTE_MAIN) {
            ExitTransition.None
        } else {
            slideOutHorizontally(
                targetOffsetX = { it },
                animationSpec = tween(300)
            )
        }
    },
) {
    composable(ROUTE_MAIN) { ... }
    composable(ROUTE_DETAILS) { ... }
    ...
}
```

As you can see in the sample above, I'm disabling the animation from the `ROUTE_MAIN` using the `EnterTransition.None` and `ExitTransition.None` based on the current route (`initialState.destination.route`) and the target route (`targetState.destination.route`).

Answer (score 2):

You need to hoist your Scaffold outside of the NavHost instead of having individual scaffolds for every screen. This way, any bottom or top app bars, including a bottom nav bar will persist during navigation. This is ideally done by having one top level scaffold for your entire app. See this answer for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74213093/21352655